# Choosing the optimal solution for a weak wi-fi signal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I am currently looking for the optimal network solution for my house, where the access point is quite far from my PC. I do not know why the wi-fi signal gets so weak so fast, but it probably is because of the thick walls and floor. I cannot get more than 10mbps using my pc's wi-fi card, while my AP can provide around 600 mbps via cable.

Note that I really am just looking for the best setup for my PC only. Other devices don't need to benefit from this setup. I have tried those solutions already :

- BPL : my lines are very bad and BPL does not provide any satisfactory performance
- Cable : for diverse reasons, I can't just put a cable through the house to my PC, so that's excluded.
- wifi repeater : I don't like repeaters usually, and this time proved me right since it doesn't seem any setup with a repeater was able to improve my performance. I've tried with different places around the house and if anything, it somehow made it worse.

So here I am, looking for a solution. I've thought of 2 so far :

- using a meshed wifi. This isn't my go-to solution because I'm not really knowledgeable about these and they tend to be very expensive.
- Using a pair of directional wi-fi antennas, one connected to the AP, and one to my PC.
  However, my searches on the directional antennas couldn't really help me decide if it is a good solution over such a short distance, or how to set it up.

I would be very grateful if you could inform me about the feasability and possible performance of such a setup using directional antennas.

Additional information about my access point :

- it does not support PoE
- it does not have RP-SMA connectors on the outside (Livebox 5 from Orange, France)

Here is a ms paint blueprint of my house to make visualizing the situation easier :

house visualization
[image]

Comment: Can you run an ethernet cable to *somewhere* halfway to the PC (e.g. second floor staircase)?

Comment: no, anything after the entry of the first floor staircase is a no-go for cables

Comment: Re: "I can't just put a cable through the house": You don't string Ethernet cables through your living spaces. You install it in the walls, terminated in in-wall jacks, like a civilized person. If you've got thick walls that Wi-Fi signals don't penetrate well, you certainly don't want your home's network infrastructure to depend on Wi-Fi backhauls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think anyone can definitively answer your question without a site visit, butsome thoughts that may be useful -

1. Move your main AP (or, using ethernet deploy a second AP) closer to the computer of interest. Over simplifying, putting the unit in the centre of the house will give the best result.  This is to say that if you can recable so as to move the AP directly above the computer you will likely get improved performance.   Depending on your house construction and size of passage putting it above the stairwell might also help.
2. Use a quality AP. There are vast differences between cheap routers with built in APs and prosumer/professional gear.  I have had great success with ASUS gear, and Ubiquity and Microtic stuff is prosumer and well rated.
3. Bear in mind frequencies, interference and channel width.  2.4 gig is better at distance and penetrating walls then 5 gig, but has a lot less spectrum.  There are only 3 non-overlapping channels in this band, and your neighbours could be causing interference.  Relicating your device can help, as can changing frequency, but an oft forgotten tool is to ensure client AP and computer both have multiple antennas so they can do "beam forming" - ie cancel out noise from other transmitters.
4. Directional antenna can help by focussing the beam in a direction and reducing noise.  That said you are not going through clear space so this affect may not be as strong.
5. You said bpl is no good.  I am unfamiliar with it, but I assume its dimilar to Ethernet over powerline.  It may be worth revisiting this. Again, different gear can perform massively diffetently in the same conditions, but also trying different outlets/circuits can make a difference - especially if you can avoid jumping between RCD's.
6. Newer standard equipment is typically faster and has a longer range, Cheap isp equopment very seldom has the latest standards, but your computer may need an upgrade as well.  Of-course you will never get WIFIs rated performance outside lab conditions.

Expecting "line speed" ovet WIFI may be unrealistic - but done right you could br able to increade your throughput by a factor of 5-20 using the above.

Comment: I have followed your advice and bought newer BPL modules. And I was surprised ! The new module achieve 100 mbps, over 50 times the old modules' rate. I didn't know this could make such a difference. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a weak signal causing the issue? When the PC is moved near the router, is the speed much better? If it *is* a weak signal, you can try the following:

- Some WiFi cards have limitations. An external (USB) adapter with an antenna, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KHV7H1S), might help improve I/O as well as signal strength. You can use a **short**, high-quality, USB extension cable to allow the adapter to be moved around the room for optimal signal strength. Use a tool such as Nirsoft's [WiFi Info View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) on Windows or [wavemon](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/03/wavemon-live-wifi-signal-strength/) on Linux to optimize the antenna position.
- [Some WiFi frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) (900 MHz, 2.4 GHz) penetrate better than others (5 GHz and higher). Also, some channels may be in use by a neighbor, or subject to more noise than others, and some channels offer higher power limits. It is also possible to pair channels, using [two or more at once](https://www.extremenetworks.com/extreme-networks-blog/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-multi-channel-wi-fi/) for higher throughput. Try [setting the channel(s)](https://www.alphr.com/change-wi-fi-channel-most-popular-routers/) used by the router.

Comment: I double down on this post.  I have had some success with a third party wifi-antenna over the little rubber thingy that comes with cards.  I have had some success with the frequencies as some parts of my house seem to get "through the wall" better at 2.4 where other parts seem to do better at 5ghz.  Also, keep in mind where your microwave is.  It will hose the 2.4ghz band when running.

Comment: thank you for your answer, though it does not answer my question, it does try to help. As a matter of fact I am already using a usb antenna to even get the signal from my PC. It is indeed the signal being too weak since I have great speeds with my laptop near the access point.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the antenna of your AP isn't a true isotropic radiator. That being said, it is only omnidirectional horizontally, but vertically it is lobe-shaped, with its maximum slightly above the ground plane of the antenna. Deviating too far up or down has the signal deteriorate quickly, reaching virtually zero directly above or below the antenna.

That being said, if you'd plot the field strength emitted by the antenna, you'd notice that you have a rather narrow vertical angle of aperture, with the maximum slightly above the antenna's ground plane, in every horizontal direction away from the antenna. However, depending on how long said antenna is in relation to the wave length of the signal, you may have secondary, tertiary, and so on lobes that are emitted at a steeper angle, but which are significantly weaker than the primary lobe (for λ/4 you'd only have the primary lobe, up to λ/2 you'd have a side lobe, up to 3/4*λ you'd get two, and so on). However, installing too long an antenna has other ramifications.

That being said, you have multiple options:

- Move the AP down to ground level. Your PC would then reside somewhere within the angle of aperture of your AP so that you are going to get a stronger signal.
- Tilt the antenna (and by doing so its ground plane) so that you get your box into its angle of aperture. This, however, doesn't work as well as the previous situation since the floor (and especially the subsoil) is going to interfere.
- Use a directional antenna on your AP (especially if the antenna on your PC is long enough to generate side lobes). This way you are also limiting the horizontal angle of aperture and get a significant gain in its primary direction of transmission. A long Yagi consisting of 8 elements gets a gain of about 10 dBd in its primary direction (both RX and TX), which should suffice to give you a stronger signal that reaches your box. However, make sure that the Yagi matches the band that you are using (you cannot use one designed for 2.4 GHz whilst using the 5 GHz band and vice versa), because the antenna's impedance needs to match the cable used between the Wifi NIC and the antenna (since it's coax, the impedance most likely is 50 Ω). If it doesn't, part of the signal is reflected back to the NIC, causing the quality of the signal to deteriorate quickly (loss in signal strength, reflected signals interfering with those being received).